# Websphere multiple authentication provider

Tags: websphere-liberty

I am looking for some information about using multiple authentication provider with WebSphere Liberty at the same time. Requirement is to have AD (LDAP) auth as main authentication and for users not allowed to be listed in AD have a simple database for authentication.
Thanks for any hints.

Comment: You've asked a pretty broad question, so here is the link to the general authentication documentation for Liberty: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_sec_authenticating.html

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom user registry to meet these requirements:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_sec_custmr.html

If you're looking for the solution of security domains provided in WAS Classic (the full profile), please open an RFE and be sure to vote for it!
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/?BRAND_ID=181